# Printing Json file in jquery mobile by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-mobile

Basically I've been successfully printing a json file with a js function in html. I have since switched over to jquery mobile and tried to modify my function to match with the jquery mobile syntax. I have manually added what the function should be printing out and it displays correctly so there is a problem with the function. I am trying to print in ui-grid-d and have an array looping through each of the blocks in order to keep correct syntax

JS Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var grid= new Array();
grid[0]= "<div class='ui-block-a'>";
grid[1]= "<div class='ui-block-b'>";
grid[2]= "<div class='ui-block-c'>";
grid[3]= "<div class='ui-block-d'>";
var j=0;


$(function (){

  var imp = "Json/contents.json"

  $.getJSON(imp, function(data) {
    var toc="";
    var pos=grid[j];
    $.each(data.tcontent, function(index, item) {
      toc += pos + item.url + '<div class="grid">' + "<p class='gridtext'>" + item.Chapter + ":" + item.Name  + "</p>" +  "</div>" + "</a>" + "</div>"
    });

 //incriment j
 j++;

 //if j is out of bounds return j to 0
 if(j==4){
  j=0;
}
$(toc).appendTo(".ui-grid-d");
 //alert(toc)
 });
});
</script>
```

Json File (forget about the background attribute):

```
{
 "tcontent": [{
"Chapter": "1",
"Name": "General Principles of Antibiotic Perscribing",
"url":"<a href='general_principles.html'>",
"Background":"yellow"
}, {
"Chapter": "2",
"Name": "Note on meticillin resistant SA",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "3",
"Name": "Empirical Therapy Guidelines:",
"url": "<a href='empirical.html'>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "4",
"Name": "Treatment of Malaria",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "5",
"Name": "Antibiotic Prophylaxis:",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "6",
"Name": "Aminoglycoside and Glycopeptide dosing and monitoring:",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "7",
"Name": "Splenectomy: vaccination and antibiotic prophylaxis",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "8",
"Name": "Restricted Antimicrobials",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "9",
"Name": "Topical Antibiotics",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "10",
"Name": "Antimicrobials and Renal Failure",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "11",
"Name": "Antimicrobials and Hepatic Disease",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "12",
"Name": "Administration of IV Antimicrobials",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}, {
"Chapter": "13",
"Name": "Penicillin allergy & other beta-lactam containing antibiotics",
"url":"<a>",
"Background":"background-color:red"
}]
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
     <body>
          <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="Page1">

            <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
              <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="flip" data-icon="back"> Back </a>
                <a href="info.html" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="flip" data-icon="info"> Info </a>
                <h2>Main Menu</h2>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" id="Page1_Content">

            <div class="ui-grid-d">



            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
                <h2>(c) Darragh O'Connor </h2>
            </div>


        </div>



</body>
```

If anyone could see the problem I'd much appreciate it. I've been racking my brains for hours.
Thanks

Comment: First thing, jQuery mobile doesn't bind to document ready (`$(function())`) - http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: corrected. $(function (){ is now $(document).bind('pageinit',function(){

Comment: have you updated your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yuLSC/)**

You need to increment `j` within the `$.each()` and also set it to 0 if j > 3. You also had a missing `<a>` tag or and extra `</a>` within the text. Your variable pos would also never change because it is outside the each() loop.  For 4 columns, the grid class should be `ui-grid-c`.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#Page1", function(){

    var toc= '';
    $.each(json.tcontent, function(index, item) {
        if (j > 3) { j = 0; }
        toc += grid[j] + item.url + '<div class="grid">' + "<a><p class='gridtext'>" + item.Chapter + ":" + item.Name  + "</p>" +  "</div>" + "</a>" + "</div>"
        j++;
    });

    $(toc).appendTo(".ui-grid-c");

});
```

Comment: I see the demo works well but for some reason it will not display when i run it in Phonegap. However when I write exactly what it should be printing out in the actual body of the html it works perfectly. Its extremely strange and I've no idea why its happening. I even put the json in the same html file and still no luck.

Comment: I don't have phonegap experience. Perhaps that needs to be a separate question as here we have solved the jQuery Mobile issue...